# Get the time when an interaction was invoked (pycord)

Tags: discord, discord.py, pycord

Without slash commands, you could use the command's context the time when the command was sent: `ctx.message.created_at`

[image: created_at: The message's creation time in UTC.]

You could use this property to timestamp embeds, like this:
[image: Today at 12:18 AM]

Is there any way to replicate this with slash commands' interactions?

Comment: ```interaction.message.created_at``` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I could find in the discord.py and pycord docs, I believe that using `interaction.message.created_at` instead of `ctx.message.created_at` should solve your problem